# Mostrar valores mas grandes y pequeños que la media en java

Tags: java

> Necesito que este codigo me diga que numeros son mas grandes y cuales
> mas pequeños que la media alguien  sabria como hacerlo?.  Este es un ejemplo de lo que quiero que el programa imprima ->Los valores mayores a 5.2
> son: 6 8 y los valores más pequeños que 5.2 son: 4 4 3

```
  package com.company;
    
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // write your code here
            int i;
            int[] numeros = new int[5];
    
    
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            for(i=0; i<numeros.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("Introduzca valor posicion %d: ", i+1);
                numeros[i] = teclado.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("Has introducido los siguientes valores: "+numeros[0]+" "+ numeros[1]+" "+numeros[2]+" "+numeros[3]+" "+numeros[4]);
    
            int sum = 0;
            for (int numero : numeros) sum += numero;
            System.out.println("La suma es: "+sum);
    
            double media = 0.0;
            for (int numero : numeros) {
                media = media + numero;
            }
            media = media / numeros.length;
    
            System.out.println("La media es: "+media);
    
           
    
    
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tendrías que hacer seria declarar dos `array` de tipo `int` e inicializarlas.

```
int[] mayores = new int[numeros.length];
int[] menores = new int[numeros.length];
```

Despues realizar un bucle recorriendo tu array `numero` y asignar cada elemento al array correspondiente en funcion si el numero es mayor o menor a la media.

```
for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
        if (numeros[j] > media) {
            mayores[j] = numeros[j];
        } else {
            menores[j] = numeros[j];
        }
    }
```

Por ultimo tan solo haría falta mostrarlo por consola:

```
System.out.println("\nValores mayores a la media: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < mayores.length; x++) {
        if (mayores[x] != 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + mayores[x]);
        }
    }

System.out.println("\nValores menores a la media: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < menores.length; x++) {
        if (menores[x] != 0) {
            System.out.print(" " + menores[x]);
        }
    }
```

*Ouptput:*

```
Introduzca valor posicion 1: 1
Introduzca valor posicion 2: 2
Introduzca valor posicion 3: 3
Introduzca valor posicion 4: 4
Introduzca valor posicion 5: 5
Has introducido los siguientes valores: 1 2 3 4 5
La suma es: 15
La media es: 3.0

Valores mayores a la media: 
 4 5
Valores menores a la media: 
 1 2 3
```

Tu ejemplo completo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        int i;
        int[] numeros = new int[5];
        int[] mayores = new int[numeros.length];
        int[] menores = new int[numeros.length];
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Introduzca valor posicion %d: ", i + 1);
            numeros[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Has introducido los siguientes valores: " + numeros[0] + " " + numeros[1] + " " + numeros[2]
                + " " + numeros[3] + " " + numeros[4]);

        int sum = 0;
        for (int numero : numeros)
            sum += numero;
        System.out.println("La suma es: " + sum);

        double media = 0.0;
        for (int numero : numeros) {
            media = media + numero;
        }
        media = media / numeros.length;

        System.out.println("La media es: " + media);

        for (int j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
            if (numeros[j] > media) {
                mayores[j] = numeros[j];
            } else {
                menores[j] = numeros[j];
            }

        }

        System.out.println("\nValores mayores a la media: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < mayores.length; x++) {
            if (mayores[x] != 0) {
                System.out.print(" " + mayores[x]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nValores menores a la media: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < menores.length; x++) {
            if (menores[x] != 0) {
                System.out.print(" " + menores[x]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```